# Correct use of CPU registers -- scheduling concepts

Tags: assembly, mips, scheduling, cpu-registers

Warning: my question is more theoretical and less practical. Unfortunately I didn't manage to discover much info googling it.

Having started some basic MIPS32 assembly programming, for educational purposes, I can't seem to understand something: 
If someone writes a program in MIPS assembly, and this program is run on a MIPS **multitasking** operating system, how does the **process scheduling** works?

1) For example, in a multitasking environment, when the switch to another process must occur, does the OS store the registers' values somewhere in memory and then wipes the registers so the next process can use them?
2) What is the appropriate use of registers? Are all temp registers ($t0-$t7) at my disposal at any time? Can I use some of the other registers whenever I like?

Comment: Great question, i think i know the answers but I'm going to sit back seeing as my Assembly class was a decade ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1), yes, when switching from process A to process B, the OS has to store A's registers in memory, and it restores B's registers from a similar storage location.

Because of this, a process has the illusion that it is in complete control of the processor's full register set; all of the general purpose registers on MIPS can be used by the process however it wants (with the exception of registers 26 and 27 which are reserved for the kernel). The more complex conventions for what registers are for temporary values and such are so that functions within one process can cooperate properly, passing values and not stepping on each other's registers.

Gritty details on the ABI can be found here:
http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/0640/SGI_Developer/books/Mpro_n32_ABI/sgi_html/ch02.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the mips registers reference, it makes sense. Is there any chance you can refer to some process scheduling material too?

Comment: @EliasBats : The fundamental concept of switching processes is the [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch). The OS takes control of a running process by [preemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Preemptive_multitasking), commonly. Actual process scheduling (deciding what process to run) is a huge field, one of the simplest methods is [round-robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling). Sorry for all the wikipedia links, the topics are general enough that that is probably the best place to start.

Comment: **context switch** was what I was looking for. Now I have googled it and there are dozens of helpful articles and textbooks, thank you.